# Why revolution slider jquery plugin is not working in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, revolution-slider

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url(); ?>site-assets/plugins/revolution/css/settings.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url(); ?>site-assets/plugins/revolution/css/layers.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?= base_url(); ?>site-assets/plugins/revolution/css/navigation.css">
```

Here are my plugin files but it could not attach the slider on my homepage. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please confirm if there is any error in browser's console or not?

Comment: @VINEETSHARMA Yes, See:  jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:7 Failure at Loading:revolution.extension.migration.min.js on Path:plugins/revolution/js/extensions/

Comment: @VINEETSHARMA that's working properly in the original theme, but not in the codeigniter.

Comment: It is trying to load a file "revolution.extension.migration.min.js", but that file is not available on that path. Maybe you don't have all the files needed to make the slider work.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\sma_ci\site-assets\plugins\revolution\js\extensions\revolution.extension.migration.min.js Here is the full path of that js. It is working on the HTML theme but not in the CodeIgniter, I don't know why.